# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, swift3

I am getting an error that in the line "self.email = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["email"] as! String" saying that it could not cast value of type 'NSNull'. How do I fix the error? I thought that since I have a function toAnyObject that it would convert everything to a String.

```
struct User {
    var email: String!
    var uid: String!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var key: String = ""

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.email = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["email"] as! String
        self.uid = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as! String
        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        self.key = snapshot.key
    }

    init(email: String, uid: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.uid = uid
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any] {
        return ["email":self.email, "uid":self.uid]
    }
}
```

Comment: `if let snap =  snapshot.value as? [String:Any] { self.email =  snap["email"] as! String }` Dont do force unwrap as it might be null like in ur case ..snapshot.value is null

Comment: see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253870/could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsnull-to-nsstring-in-parsing-json-in-swift

Comment: if I wanted to add another field, should I simply add to that? For some reason, that code gives me an error.                        
     if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            self.email = snap["email"] as! String
            self.firstname = snap["firstname"] as! String }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As El Captain v2.0 pointed out, don´t force unwrap a value as it might be `nil` and you´ll get a crash. Use `if let` instead:

```
// if snap has a value, then you can use the value. Otherwise not, you can call an else if you want to.
if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] { 
    self.email = snap["email"] as! String 
}
```

And I would skip the `as! String` too and would have done it like this instead, incase of you don´t get the `email` value.

```
if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String:Any], let email = snap["email"] as? String  { 
    // Use email in here now
    print(email)
}
```

**So if you have other fields you want to get, just add them into the `if-statement`.**

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct User {

    var email: String!
    var uid: String!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var key: String = ""

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot){

        self.email = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["email"] as! String
        self.uid = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as! String
        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        self.key = snapshot.key

    }

    init(email: String, uid: String){

        if let snap = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
        // Do not unwrap forcefully, instead use as mentioned below 
        // so that in case snap["email"] gives null that could be 
        //handled. 
        //Also please check that whether you have "firstname" var 
        //present in not in your code and dictionary both. 
        self.email = snap["email"] as? String ?? "" //Provide some default value or empty string
        }
        self.uid = uid
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> [String: Any]{
        return ["email":self.email, "uid":self.uid]
    }
    }
```